# Java Button acts like Enter Key

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am new to Java and am in the process of making a GUI of CLI application of Poker Game. It requires "Enter Key" to continue. I have tried to find out if there is some Event Handler for "Enter Key" so that I could change that Event to Mouse Button. But unfortunately I could not find any such thing. Now I have thought of passing carriage return to Java Console onClick Event. I have tried:

```
ContinueBtn = new JButton();
ContinueBtn.addMouseListener(this);
 .
 .
 .
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
     System.out.println("\r\n");

     //OR
     char c = (char) KeyEvent.VK_ENTER;
     System.out.println(c)

     //OR
     BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
     out.write("\r\n");
     out.newLine();
     out.flush();

     //OR
     BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
     out.write((char)10); /*OR*/ out.write((char)13);
 }
```

It is still not working. Can anyone suggest what should I do?

Comment: please learn java naming conventionss and stick to them

Answer (score 3):

Add proper `Action` or `ActionListener`, then implements `KeyBindings`, output form 
`KeyBindings` should be `javax.swing.Action`, inside this `Action` call

```
myButton.doClick()
```

that invoke `Action` or `ActionListener` added to the `JButton`

Comment: Can you please explain what should I write in OnClick Event of Jbutton?

Answer (score 0):

For 'Enter' on JButtons, you probably want to use `JRootPane.setDefaultButton()`. Both JWindow and JDialog have a `getRootPane()` method.

The only trick is that the window / dialog has to be visible already to set the default button. I usually just override `setVisible()` in the windows that need a default button:

```
public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
  }

    super.setVisible(b);
}
```

Comment: If the window / dialog needs to be visible to call `setDefaultButton` that method wouldn't work. It calls `setDefaultButton` before allowing the `JWindow` or `JDialog` to become visible.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use `setDefaultButton(...)`. -1, for suggesting to override setVisible(). This is not required. The frame does not have to be visible when setting the default button property of the root pane.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I DONT want to use JButton when I Press Enter Key.
I want to pass ENTER Key to Java Console when I Click on JButton. What should I write in onClick Event Listener of JButton?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question, but from what i understand about your situation this might help.

(anything like a button)ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)

Comment: I want to pass ENTER KEY to java console when I Click on JButton. What should I write in onClick listener of JButton?

Answer (score 0):

Key bindings in Swing are handled with `InputMap`s and `ActionMap`s.

Sun has a nice [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) on the key binding API. The tutorial has this to say:

> An alternative to key bindings is using key listeners. Key listeners
>   have their place as a low-level interface to keyboard input, but for
>   responding to individual keys key bindings are more appropriate and
>   tend to result in more easily maintained code. Key listeners are also
>   difficult if the key binding is to be active when the component
>   doesn't have focus. Some of the advantages of key bindings are they're
>   somewhat self documenting, take the containment hierarchy into
>   account, encourage reusable chunks of code (Action objects), and allow
>   actions to be easily removed, customized, or shared. Also, they make
>   it easy to change the key to which an action is bound. Another
>   advantage of Actions is that they have an enabled state which provides
>   an easy way to disable the action without having to track which
>   component it is attached to.

[`java.awt.event.KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) ([`KeyListener` Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)).

Comment: I have seen this tutorial and made this program and run it. When I press ENTER Key it gives key code 10.
Now, I have written these lines in my OnClick Listener of JButton
    System.out.println(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // This line writes 10 in console window
    System.out.println((char)10); // This line adds new line to java console but still does not act as enter key.
    System.out.println("\r\n"); // This line adds new line to java console but still does not act as enter key.

Comment: @patanni There are three components to the java console. System.in, System.out and System.err. Pressing the enter key appends `\r\n` to the readable stream System.in. Appending `\r\n` to System.out will *not* make it accessible to System.in. (I assume this is what you're trying to do.) It you want to write `\r\n` you need to create a `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` pair and use `System.setIn(yourPipedInputStream)`.